# Can I cure a Spawn of Kyuss in an Antimagic Field with Lesser Restoration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, antimagic-field

If I cast *lesser restoration* on a Spawn of Kyuss, who is within an Antimagic Field (as per the spell), from outside the Antimagic Field, what happens?

A Spawn of Kyuss has the Worms trait which says:

> If the Spawn of Kyuss is targeted by an effect that cures disease or removes a curse, all the worms infesting it wither away, and it loses its Burrowing Worm action.

I am targeting the Spawn of Kyuss with *lesser restoration* which would cause cure disease normally, but...

> ***Targeted Effects:*** Spells and other magical effects ... that target a creature or an object in the sphere have no effect on that target.
>
> [from *antimagic field*]

Does the Worms trait trigger from this casting of *lesser restoration*?

---

I ask because the Worms trait only says it needs to be targeted by the disease-curing effect, not that it needs to be affected by it.

Answer (score 17):

### You burn your spell slot.

The text reads that it is targeted by an effect. The Anti-Magic Field says the effect never takes place.

Yes you can target your *spell* on the creature within the Anti-Magic Field but it never takes effect. This is yet another example of poor word choices on the part of the developers or reading too much into their word choices.

If things too literally you take... path to the Dark Side this is.

The Worms don't die simply because you targeted them, the effect also has to apply, in this case Anti-Magic Field nullifies said effect therefore the Spawn of Kyuss is not affected.

Answer (score 10):

## Nothing (except losing a spell slot)

Per *antimagic field*:

> Spells and other magical effects...that target a creature or an object
> in the sphere **have no effect** on that target.

and the Worms trait says:

> If the Spawn of Kyuss is **targeted by an effect** that cures disease...

Worms withering away is in fact an effect resulting from a spell or effect targeting the Spawn of Kyuss. *Antimagic field* says that targeted spells "have no effect on that target". Effects, in this case including killing worms. So the worms are not affected.